# Implement new google cardboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-cardboard, google-vr

you probably know, GVRSDK is deprecated and it includes UIWebview reference which is problematic because iOS is removing UIWebView. Currently submitted applications receive a warning, but eventually will be auto-rejected.

That's why I try to implement the new google cardboard:
https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/ios/quickstart

Problem is there is no carthage, no pod.
Did you try to use this sdk in you own project ?

I am trying but unsuccessfully :( The documents is rather useless ...
Do you have a simple idea how to use this SDK? Maybe I miss something ?

Thanks